# Terminology: Does a judge have a career in "litigation"?

Tags: phrase-requests, poetry

I'm working on a song parody, satirizing a notably litigious group of people, and have run up against a little issue of "accuracy of terminology" and "phrasing that reflects my intentions" vs. scansion.  Ideally, I'd like my song's narrator to possibly be a judge or a lawyer, left ambiguous: someone whose profession is in criminal law, though if I have to choose just one, it would be the voice of a judge.  Could "Litigation's my career" apply to a judge, rather than only to a lawyer?  "Adjudication's my career" would fit only a judge.  Are there other "[X] is my career" terms which would cover both cases while still being short, and relatively common in the English language such that a listener who's not a legal expert would have no trouble understanding it in song lyrics?

Thanks!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because that is not a question about law. This belongs to a language specific stack, such as [English.SE]

Comment: Court? Being judgmental? Playing God?

Comment: No, they have careers hearing litigation arguments. How many syllables?

Comment: "The law is my career".

Comment: The bench is my career. Yes, Your Honor are words I love to hear.

Comment: I need scansion "DA da DA da DA (beat) da DA", optionally leading with an unstressed syllable.  "THE LAW (beat) is MY caREER", as Stuart F suggests, isn't without potential, but it's short by a couple of syllables.  "To WORK in LAW is MY (beat) caREER" would be closer.  "WorKING in LAW etc." has the right idea and syllable count but breaks the scansion of "working".  EDIT: TimR's "The bench is my career" is back to referring to a judge but not a lawyer.

Comment: Who cares about correctness in a song? Say what you WANNA SAY. Note that most litigation is under civil, not criminal law.

Comment: I want to say that a particular group of people who regularly get criminal charges are idiots for how they attempt to deal with them, and are really annoying to the judges and lawyers who have to face them.  *I* care about correctness in a song, because misusing words confuses listeners and scansion is important.

Comment: @MooningattheBeys: "AppLYing LAW is MY (etc)"?

Comment: W.S. Gilbert's solution, in *Trial by Jury* was for the judge to have been a lawyer earlier in his career.

Answer (score 2):

That's iffy. A judge does not litigate, lawyers do that. But a judge presides over litigation. So could he say "litigation is my job"? Sort of. Just like, could someone who works at a hardware store say "home repair is my job"? If he doesn't actually repair any homes himself, but sells people the tools and supplies they need to do it? I'd say yes ... sort of.

In this case, perhaps you could say "the courtroom is my career". I can't think of any other more general phrasing. Perhaps someone who works in law could give a better answer.

Comment: Or "the law is my career", I guess!

Comment: I might switch it around (and change the rhyme): "My career is in the court of law".  Or even "My vocation is the court of law", to be synecdoche-y.